# store imshow - Matlab

Tags: matlab, imshow

How can I store the reduced color imshow in an image object so I can further use it for other analysis.

Source:

```
I =  imread('C:\eg.jpg');

[X_no_dither,map]= rgb2ind(I,8,'nodither');
figure, imshow(X_no_dither,map)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ind2rgb` to convert it *back* to an RGB image using your new indexed image and colormap

```
rgb_image = ind2rgb(X_no_dither, map);
```

If you want, you can then save this resulting image to a file with `imwrite`

```
imwrite(rgb_image, 'newimage.png')
```